# How do I update Excel's vlookup formula for multiple workbooks?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have thousands of Excel files with vlookup formula. How do I update the formula in all files at once? The files were moved and and I need it to be looking up in a new path.

Comment: Excel VBA, loop through all files and do a find (old path) and replace (new path). Obviously back up all files and test on a few before running it on all files...

Comment: Thank you. Will definitely look into it.

Comment: Is the formula found in the same cell in all the workbooks?

Comment: Most of them are in different cells. Only few have same cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a one-stop way if there are only a couple files which you can update manually. But if you really have a host of files, you propably have to go down the road of a VBA script.

First the easy way:

- Open the file you want to change the link in.
- In the ribbon go to the 'Data' tab and click the 'Edit Links' button.
- There select the file that was moved to a new directory and click the button 'Change Source...'
  [image]
- Save the file and you're done

For processing many files at once this can take quite some time, so you can use a macro here. I once had a similar issue where a server in the office was replaced. Sharing the code here, not claiming it to be perfect.

- Open a new workbook and press 'alt' + F11 (to open the VBA editor).
- There paste the following code.

Adjust the two constants according to your paths:

```
Option Explicit
Sub replace_links_in_all_files()
    Dim base_file As String, base_path As String, files() As String, index As Long
    Const old_path = "INSERT YOUR OLD PATH HERE"
    Const new_path = "INSERT YOUR NEW PATH HERE"

    'On error show a message and abort
    On Error GoTo error_message

    'Disable screen updating to speed things up, display in status bar
    Application.StatusBar = "Updating links..."
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Ask for base path
    base_file = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files (*.*),*.*")

    'End script, if dialogue was cancelled
    If base_file Like False Then Exit Sub

    'Cut string from the selected file
    Do While (InStr(base_file, "\") > 0)
        base_path = base_path & Left(base_file, InStr(base_file, "\"))
        base_file = Right(base_file, Len(base_file) - InStr(base_file, "\"))
    Loop

    'Search the selected path and everything below for Excel files ending in .xlsx
    files = fileSearch(base_path, "*.xlsx")

    'Edit all found files
    For index = LBound(files) To UBound(files)
        Call update_links(files(index), old_path, new_path)
    Next index

    'Reenable screen updating and reset status bar
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False

    'Show info box
    MsgBox prompt:="Skript completed successfully.", Title:="Done"
    Exit Sub

error_message:
    MsgBox "An error occurred. The script cannot be continued.", vbCritical, "Aborting"
    End Sub

'-------------------------------------------------------'
'Replaces the legacy FileSearch-Object since Office 2007'
'-------------------------------------------------------'
Function fileSearch(path As String, name As String) As String()

    Dim filesystem As Scripting.FileSystemObject, sourceDir As Scripting.folder, subDir As Scripting.folder, foundFile As Scripting.file
    Dim found_files() As String, found_sub() As String, length As Long, i As Long
    ReDim found_files(0)

    'Open filesystem
    Set filesystem = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    'Set folder to search
    Set sourceDir = filesystem.getfolder(path)

    'Check every file in the folder
    On Error GoTo no_access
    For Each foundFile In sourceDir.files
        If foundFile.name Like name Then

        'Append found files to resulting array
        If found_files(0) <> "" Then
            length = length + 1
            ReDim Preserve found_files(length)
        End If
        found_files(length) = foundFile.path
        End If
    Next foundFile

    'Search all subfolders
    For Each subDir In sourceDir.subfolders
        found_sub = fileSearch(subDir.path, name)
        If found_sub(0) <> "" Then

            'Append found files to string, making sure the first entry doesn't stay empty
            If found_files(0) <> "" Then length = length + 1
            ReDim Preserve found_files(length + UBound(found_sub))
            For i = 0 To UBound(found_sub) Step 1
                found_files(length + i) = found_sub(i)
            Next i
            length = length + UBound(found_sub)
        End If
    Next subDir

no_access:
    fileSearch = found_files
    Exit Function

End Function

Private Sub update_links(ByVal filename As String, ByVal old_path, ByVal new_path)

    Dim file As Workbook, sheet As Worksheet

    'Open workbook, display error and abort on error
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error GoTo cannot_open
    Set file = Workbooks.Open(filename, 2, False, , "", "", True, , , True, False)

    'Revert to default error handling
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Cycle through every sheet
    For Each sheet In file.Worksheets
        On Error GoTo unknown_ref_error
        sheet.Cells.Replace What:=old_path, Replacement:=new_path, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next sheet

    'Save file
    On Error GoTo cannot_save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    file.Close savechanges:=True, filename:=file.path & "\" & file.name
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

cannot_open:
    MsgBox ("The file " & filename & " can't be accessed. (is it password protected?)")
    Exit Sub

cannot_save:
    MsgBox ("The file " & filename & " could not be saved.")
    Exit Sub

unknown_ref_error:
    MsgBox ("File " & filename & " : In sheet '" & sheet.name & "' had a reference with unknown error.")
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

- When you launch the script, you're asked to navigate to a folder (and choose any file inside, doesn't matter which one). The script then goes into every file inside this folder and all subdirectories and updates the links. **Careful!** If there are other unavailable links or you have a typo in your paths, this may irrevokably break files! **Always backup first!**

Comment: This works perfectly!! Really appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the path are the same in formula, you can use **Replace** feature:

[image]

Comment: Tried this but I still have to manually change them 1 by 1.